# Refer to child class foreign key in base abstract model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, abstract-class

I am trying to access the child model foreign key in base abstract model so I don't have to repeat the foreign key in each of the child model.

Here is my code:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    child_field = models.ForeignKey(to='child_class_either_ModelA_OR_ModelB')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class ModelA(BaseModel):
    ....

class ModelB(BaseModel):
    ....
```

I want to refer the child model in base abstract model.

Is there a way to use an child model in base model?

Comment: I added a potential answer to your problem. Did it work for you or did you face any issues with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the fields in the abstract `BaseModel` would be [inherited](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance), then we could have `ModelA.child_field` that references itself (`ModelA`) and `ModelB.child_field` that references itself (`ModelB`) by declaring a `ForeignKey` that references itself as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey):

> To create a recursive relationship – an object that has a many-to-one relationship with itself – use `models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`.

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    child_field = models.ForeignKey(to='self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class ModelA(BaseModel):
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class ModelB(BaseModel):
    field_b = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

```
>>> from my_app.models import *
>>> 
>>> model_a_1 = ModelA.objects.create(field_a="Value 1")
>>> model_a_2 = ModelA.objects.create(field_a="Value 2", child_field=model_a_1)
>>> ModelA.objects.values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'child_field_id': None, 'field_a': 'Value 1'}, {'id': 2, 'child_field_id': 1, 'field_a': 'Value 2'}]>
>>> 
>>> model_b_3 = ModelB.objects.create(field_b="Value 3")
>>> model_b_4 = ModelB.objects.create(field_b="Value 4", child_field=model_b_3)
>>> ModelB.objects.values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'child_field_id': None, 'field_b': 'Value 3'}, {'id': 2, 'child_field_id': 1, 'field_b': 'Value 4'}]>
```

Cross-references in between different child models would fail e.g. `ModelA` linked to `ModelB`.

```
>>> model_a_5 = ModelA.objects.create(field_a="Value 5", child_field=model_b_4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot assign "<ModelB: ModelB object (2)>": "ModelA.child_field" must be a "ModelA" instance.
>>> 
>>> model_b_6 = ModelB.objects.create(field_b="Value 6", child_field=model_a_2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot assign "<ModelA: ModelA object (2)>": "ModelB.child_field" must be a "ModelB" instance.
```